# Complex sort of object list based on attribute

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

I have a list of objects I have read from a json file. I want to sort that list based on an object attribute but this normally simple task becomes a bit more complicated for my skills because of the fact that in some objects this attribute is missing. So the interpreter produces an error when it tries to access the first object in which this attribute is missing.

The error produced:

```
KeyError: 'event_readtime'
```

The line producing it:

```
self.data.sort(key=lambda obj: getattr(obj, obj["event_readtime"]), reverse=True)
```

What I'm basically asking is for a way to check if the key "event_readtime" exists in the dictionary object each json file is being read into and incorpotate that into the key predicate.

EDIT: An important detail I forgot to mention is that the attribute is of type `int`. So the sorting (being reverse) should sort the numbers in descending order. Also, the objects that don't have this attribute should be ideally at the end of the list.

Comment: You may help answers of this question by giving some examples. In particular, the question can't really be answered without specifying *where in the ordering* should the objects come that *don't* have this attribute. i.e. if they don't have them, should they be at the end or beginning of the list. I'm sure someone will be pleased to help you out.

Comment: You're quite right, I'll elaborate further.

Answer (score 2):

The following code should solve your problem:

```
self.data.sort(key=lambda obj: obj.get("event_readtime")), reverse=True)
```

This makes use of Python dictionaries' [.get() method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get), which will fetch the value at the provided key and, if the key is not found, will return `None`.

Note that you may also provide a default value for `get()` in case the return value of `None` doesn't work for you, for example, if you want all items that do not have a "event_readtime" sorted to the end of the list, you might want to try the following:

```
import sys
MAX = sys.maxint # The largest int value available
self.data.sort(key=lambda obj: obj.get("event_readtime", MAX)), reverse=True)
```

Comment: upvoted. Please elaborate a bit and explain why it works/what `.get` does and what the end result will be

Comment: This normally works but...any version of that, which works with an integer attribute?